# Pasting Html text in Edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

How to restrict HTML content while pasting some text from a website to our EditText?.

Example I copy some text from a website, when I paste the text in my EditText the HTML font and text size also comes along. What i want is to restrict any HTML content while I paste the text. Tried several methods using TextWatcher and InputFilters, but none of them are working. Whatsapp is handling it somehow. Please help.

Edit: The string can be converted to non-HTML but how to make changes in EditText?

Comment: @Nj I do not think this question is duplicate of tagged post. Please read once before marking duplicate to any answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a **Rich Text Formatting** issue.

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758698/paste-without-rich-text-formatting-into-edittext) you can add a `TextWatcher` to your `EditText` and use this method:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable string)
{
    CharacterStyle[] toBeRemovedSpans = string.getSpans(0, string.length(),
                                                MetricAffectingSpan.class);
    for (int index = 0; index < toBeRemovedSpans; index++)
        string.removeSpan(toBeRemovedSpans[index]);
    }
}
```

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24777290/5457878

Comment: It still leaves all the spaces around the text

Comment: Could you give a small example?

Comment: if i try to paste a text from website. The extra empty spaces still show up.

Comment: It's ugly, but you could use `trim()` or a `Regex` to remove whitespace.